# creating a sql query with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am having this problem and I am trying to come up with the best and most efficient solution. I have a php website with 19 different inputs, all of them are optional and I am using the get method. With those inputs, i have to find the information that matches the data base and return it. The problem I am having is creating the query that will work.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TEST.table";
if(($_GET['Transmission_Line_Designation'] ==="") && ($_GET['Switch_Number'] === "") && ($_GET['Telecom_Circuit_Number'] === "")
    && ($_GET['Transmitter_Frequency'] === "") && ($_GET['Receiver_Frequency'] === "") && ($_GET['power_level'] === "")
    && ($_GET['Phase'] === "") && ($_GET['Modulate'] === "") && ($_GET['trap_type'] === "") &&  ($_GET['line_tuner_type'] === ""))
    //checks if there were no input, if there werent any, display all columns and rows from the data base
{

}
    else
{
```

This is where i'm having the problem, if the users inputs the first input, it will work , however, if the user leaves the first input blank, the query that comes out is "where and" something something, I was thinking about using a lot of if loops to check conditions and add a flag but I am pretty sure there is an easier way to do it.

```
        $query.= " where ";
        if
        $query .= ($_GET['Transmission_Line_Designation'] === "") ? '' :  'Line_Designation = "'.$_GET['Transmission_Line_Designation'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Switch_Number'] === "") ? '' :  ' and Switch_Number = "'.$_GET['Switch_Number'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Telecom_Circuit_Number'] === "") ? '' :  ' and Telecom_Circuit_Number = "'.$_GET['Telecom_Circuit_Number'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Transmitter_Frequency'] === "") ? '' :  ' and Transmitter_Frequency = "'.$_GET['Transmitter_Frequency'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Receiver_Frequency'] === "") ? '' :  ' and Receiver_Frequency = "'.$_GET['Receiver_Frequency'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['power_level'] === "") ? '' :  ' and power = "'.$_GET['power_level'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Voltage'] === "") ? '' :  ' and voltage = "'.$_GET['Voltage'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Phase'] === "") ? '' :  ' and Phase= "'.$_GET['Phase'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Modulate'] === "") ? '' :  ' and Modulate = "'.$_GET['Modulate'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['trap_type'] === "") ? '' :  ' and trap = "'.$_GET['trap_type'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['line_tuner_type'] === "") ? '' :  'and ltunner = "'.$_GET['line_tuner_type'].'"';
        echo $query;
}
```

Thank you guys for your help in advance, i appreciate it.

Comment: In the future you might want to consider using prepared statements for your SQL.  Being victim to SQL injection is never fun.

Answer (score 2):

Throw in a dummy boolean expression first, so that all of your other criteria can start with "AND".  Like this:

```
        $query.= " where 1=1 ";
        if
        $query .= ($_GET['Transmission_Line_Designation'] === "") ? '' :  'AND Line_Designation = "'.$_GET['Transmission_Line_Designation'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Switch_Number'] === "") ? '' :  ' and Switch_Number = "'.$_GET['Switch_Number'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Telecom_Circuit_Number'] === "") ? '' :  ' and Telecom_Circuit_Number = "'.$_GET['Telecom_Circuit_Number'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Transmitter_Frequency'] === "") ? '' :  ' and Transmitter_Frequency = "'.$_GET['Transmitter_Frequency'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Receiver_Frequency'] === "") ? '' :  ' and Receiver_Frequency = "'.$_GET['Receiver_Frequency'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['power_level'] === "") ? '' :  ' and power = "'.$_GET['power_level'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Voltage'] === "") ? '' :  ' and voltage = "'.$_GET['Voltage'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Phase'] === "") ? '' :  ' and Phase= "'.$_GET['Phase'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['Modulate'] === "") ? '' :  ' and Modulate = "'.$_GET['Modulate'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['trap_type'] === "") ? '' :  ' and trap = "'.$_GET['trap_type'].'"';
        $query .= ($_GET['line_tuner_type'] === "") ? '' :  'and ltunner = "'.$_GET['line_tuner_type'].'"';
        echo $query;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was stuck with this problem for over a day and i dont think i would have come up with that, i still have so much to learn. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem use if? And loop?
100% sure it will better to maintaince than this code....

try:

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
   if($value !== '')
      switch($key){
         case "Modulate":
            dosomething();
            break;
      }
   }
```

It'll much better to maintaince.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, added some checking too.

```
<?php

$sql   = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";
$count = count($_GET);

if ($count) { // check if $_GET has any values at all
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        if ($value) { // check if $value not empty
            $sql .= $key . " = " . "'" . $value . "', ";
        }
    }

    $sql = rtrim($sql, ", ");
}

echo $sql;

?>
```